# Make object globally available to entire application in React

Tags: reactjs

What's the best way to make an object available to any component in a react application?

For example, I can make an api request to get a list of available rooms:

```
import axios from 'axios';
let rooms = axios.get('/api/availablerooms');
```

But, pretty much all of my components will need access to the results, so making an api call every time seems poor so to make it slightly better, I'd like to use local storage to only have to make the call once if it hasn't already been done e.g.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('rooms') == null) {
   var rooms = axios.get('/api/availablerooms');
   localStorage.setItem('rooms', rooms);
}
```

What I'd like to to, is then separate this out into a single component so that any other component that needs access to the available rooms can simply include this component and get access the "rooms" object from the local storage when the component mounts.

What would be the recommended approach to making this object available globally in React?

Comment: Rather make the call in app.js and store the result in a redux store which you will be able to access across the application.

Comment: Your use case is the standard redux use case. Try it out.

Comment: Does the response from `/api/availablerooms` have the potential to change? If so, checking for the result just once could create a caching issue.

Comment: I was trying to avoid Redux if possible as wasn't sure it was needed at this point (and I'd read introducing it when it wasn't really needed was a common pitfall), but happy to try out some examples to see if it helps.

Comment: @JakeWorth possibly yes, but so infrequently that I could just use a button to force a manual refresh of the data if required.

Comment: Could you call the API in `componentDidMount()` on a parent (`App` ?) component, and then pass the result as props to the children? And also pass a function to refresh the data? Definitely check out Redux too, but it's a lot to bring in if this is your only requirement.

Comment: I could pass it down yes, but there are quite a lot of components that might need it so it could get quite into maintainability issues. I'll have a look at redux and see if I can keep it simple, thanks.